# Does someone know a comparison between programming languages on their expressive power?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm searching for a comparison that roughly states how many lines of code I need in a given programming language to solve a given problem. I thought about using the programming language shootout source for that but perhaps there's a different source for that as well.

Thank you for your help
Tobias

Comment: http://rosettacode.org may be something.

Comment: You would probably get better answers at http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's well known that some languages have stronger "expressiveness" than others.  [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code), as mentioned by deceze is a good source for things like "hello world" (trivial thought/problem), but to get a stronger sense of how expressive a language is in relation to another, there is a good write-up post here:

http://redmonk.com/dberkholz/2013/03/25/programming-languages-ranked-by-expressiveness/

It looks across many open source projects, and compares commits of the code base by the LOC that was committed, in an attempt to gauge how verbose it was to accomplish the expression.

Of course, the assumption is that one commit roughly translates to one computational goal/thought/expression/etc.  And I think in general that's true of most coders & their codebases (we at least try our best!).